# Ubuntu SCP copy stalls

Tags: ubuntu, scp, copying

I have problem copying files to cloud servers with **SCP** from my office. When I do scp of 17MB war file it says **STALLED** and then reconnect and again says stalled like the one below:

`#scp Desktop/myapp.war user1@204.x.x.x:/tmp/`

```
user1@204.x.x.x's password: 
myapp.war                                         12% 2112KB 736.4KB/s - stalled -^
```

I checked if it the problem with my ISP but, checking the upload speed they said everything is fine from their side and personally I checked attaching the file in the gmail and it uploaded fine in 3mins usually. So I think no issue from the ISP side.

Contacted the cloud server technician if they could help, and they proved sending files between cloud servers and said everything is fine from their side.

I tried other cloud servers, tried **winSCP**, tried **rsync** but the result is same. Somehow I have to make this work as how it was, because the web-developers are waiting for the production deployment.

Today,  I took someones help to copy to the Staging cloud server allowing his ip in iptables. This means only from my office the scp stalls but from outside if you have access then everything works fine.

I'm not knowing how I could solve this issue. I think I should have very good network side knowledge. Anybody came across this?, how it could be solved?.

Please need help. Thank you!

Comment: An ugly solution is "netcat 204.x.x.x 7777 < Desktop/myapp.war" and "netcat -l -p 7777 > /tmp/". But you don't get crypted transfer this way. Try if it will work and post the result.

Comment: An [automatically-reconnecting TCP tunnel](http://serverfault.com/questions/275321/automatically-reconnecting-tcp-tunnel) would be a general workaround for this kind of unreliable network.

Comment: Anybody has any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry!, the problem is at the ISP's end and got it fixed raising 2,3 complaints.

Comment: What was the problem?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like something between you and the server is dropping connections, possibly an overloaded firewall. I'm afraid I don't have any advice on fixing that, but I'll offer a workaround.

Invoke rsync with the `--partial` option (or `-P`), or `rsync --partial-dir=.rsync-partial`. If the connection is dropped, run rsync again with the same arguments, and the copy will resume where it left off.

Comment: But the copy takes too much time of around one-and-half hour.

Comment: Is it possible having firewall overload on all the servers?

Comment: I could copy with SCP/rsync but takes more than an hour for 17 & 22 MB this was not like this before. When produced speed test statistics to isp they said everything is fine!